# How to convert *.txt file into Unicode

Tags: unicode

I have a requirement where a client will supply a file in encoding ANSI, but my system can  only successfully read a file in UNICODE. So how do I tackle this issue? I know when I "save as" the file into as UNICODE encoded the file gets picked up. It's difficult to make the client comply with our request. So can I have any batch program for this folder to convert this file into UNICODE and then pick up?

Comment: When you say 'Unicode', do you mean UTF8, UTF16, UTF32, or some other representation?  And how will you spot the source code set when it isn't Unicode?  Which platform are you on?

Comment: Most people think UTF-32 = Unicode. I blame MS and their "Save As" options for this idea being so prevalent among the masses. Sad to see a developer (who ought to know better) sharing it.

Comment: MS uses mostly UCS-2, not UTF-32.

Comment: Oh, that's right!! UCS-2 = UTF-16, this is the encoding MS incorrectly refers to as "Unicode" in their "Save As" options, I stand corrected (sorry).

Comment: No! UCS-2 is NOT the same as UTF-16. UTF-16 is a superset of UCS2 which allows for non BMP characters encoding (using surrogate pairs). Windows uses UTF-16

Answer (score 17):

[`iconv`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) can do that:

```
Usage: iconv [OPTION...] [FILE...]
Convert encoding of given files from one encoding to another.

 Input/Output format specification:
  -f, --from-code=NAME       encoding of original text
  -t, --to-code=NAME         encoding for output

 Information:
  -l, --list                 list all known coded character sets

 Output control:
  -c                         omit invalid characters from output
  -o, --output=FILE          output file
  -s, --silent               suppress warnings
      --verbose              print progress information

  -?, --help                 Give this help list
      --usage                Give a short usage message
  -V, --version              Print program version

Mandatory or optional arguments to long options are also mandatory or optional
for any corresponding short options.

For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/bugs.html>.
```

Answer (score 10):

Neither ANSI nor Unicode are encodings.You'll have to know the ANSI codepage of the input file and the Unicode encoding (UTF8 or UTF16 - LE or BE) before you can use one of the suggested tools (such as iconv)

Comment: Wish I could upvote this more. For most Windows users, "Unicode" means UTF32. Most western European languages use Latin1 codepage, so most people assume that's "ANSI" encoding (again, I blame MS for their word usage in their "Save As" options).

Comment: We could add that looking into Control Panel->Regional Settings->Advanced Options will show which ANSI code-pages are installed and used.

Comment: @JoePineda and Serge: Yes, Microsoft is definitely to blame for the confusion, but this answer ignores that reality and hence is misleading and should be deleted as it serves only to cause additional confusion. The issue is that Microsoft, whether intentional or not, misused these terms. In MS-speak and software, "Unicode" specifically means "UTF-16 Little Endian", and "ANSI" specifically means "Windows Code Page 1252". Here are two examples for ANSI: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195054.aspx and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility (Search for "1252").

Answer (score 5):

[recode](http://www.gnu.org/software/recode/recode.html) could do the job.

Answer (score 4):

You can also easily convert encodings in python:

```
inf = open("infile.txt")
data = inf.read().decode("latin1")
inf.close()

outf = open("outfile.txt", "w")
outf.write(data.encode("utf-8"))
outf.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Powershell solution

```
$lines = gc "pathToFile"
$lines | out-file -enconding Unicode
```

Answer (score 2):

You may create a simple shell script (`txt_convert.sh <infile> <outfile>`):

```
#!/bin/sh

iconv -f `file -b --mime-encoding "$1"` -t utf8 "$1" -o "$2"
```

or just use:

```
iconv -f `file -b --mime-encoding "<infile>"` -t utf8 "<infile>" -o "<outfile>"
```

Explanation: 'file' command will determine the encoding of your input file, which will be used as input encoding parameter to 'iconv', which will do the conversion to utf8 in this case (you may substitute utf-8 with whatever output charset you like and iconv supports (See: iconv -l)

Answer (score 1):

I walked through some tools mentioned above, many of them require command line.

I found a much easier way to convert files in **Windows**.

1. Install **Notepad2** (http://www.flos-freeware.ch/). It's open source and free.
2. Open the file has ANSI encoding,
3. Double Click "ANSI" word at the bottom,
4. Select new Encoding such as "utf8"
5. Save the file.

It's only a few clicks to get job done.

Plus, you can easily review the content once done to double check.

Notepad2 has various benefits over Notepad. Highlighted code, Undo/Redo etc.

:D

Comment: I fail to see how changing the encoding using the Notepad2 GUI is easier than using the command line, especially with multiple files to do?

Comment: GUI is for no brainer :X  Commandline need dependency...notepad++ is just click click click...

Answer (score 0):

Ruby oneliner, fwiw:

```
ruby -e 'STDOUT.write STDIN.read.force_encoding(Encoding::WINDOWS_1252).encode!(Encoding::UTF_8)' < infile.csv > outfile.csv
```

If your input file is horrible you might need tack `STDIN.binmode; STDOUT.binmode;` on the front of the Ruby script.